# Setting up p5.js on Atom

Tags: javascript, atom-editor, p5.js

I am a newbie to p5.js.I was wondering how do I set it up in atom using the `atom live server` .I cant figure out a way around it .Most of the tutorials on YouTube uses the `p5.dom.js` file which unfortunately is not present in the complete p5.js package provided in their website .Please do help.

Comment: If you're using a modern version of p5.js, they removed the p5.dom.js library and integrated it directly into p5.js itself. So if you run `createButton("Hello I'm a button")`, it will create a `<button>` element with the text `"Hello I'm a button"`. https://p5js.org/reference/#group-DOM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you open the [web editor](https://editor.p5js.org) behind the scenes there is actually an index.html file hidden. That file references p5.js (and in the older days of p5. it also linked to p5dom).

To replicate a live server with your sketch, make sure you have a project folder with your index.html file linking to p5.js as well as your sketch.js.

The [Getting Started](https://p5js.org/get-started/) tutorial demonstrates an example of this in the *Setting up p5.js with an editor on your own computer* section.

The live server in Atom is primitive! To use it with a p5.js project, go to File > Add Project Folder and choose the folder holding your p5.js project. This should contain your index.html, sketch.js and p5.js library for example, at minimum. And make sure your index.html is structured like in the Getting Started tutorial above. Now that this is opened, you can go to Packages > Atom Live Server > Start Server. It should launch a browser window and let you preview.

Note that if you have several projects open, the one you want to see as a preview must be the topmost project in the file viewer on the left. If it's not, drag your project folder to the top.